# How does $\cos (2z) = e^{2zi}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

In my notes, they are solving $$\int \limits_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2x)}{x^2 +1}$$ and they let $$f(z) =\frac{e^{2zi}}{z^2 +1}$$ but how did the numerator become that? I wrote it as $\cos(2z)$ and then found the residue and then used the residue theorem and got the answer wrong.

Comment: Using $e^{2zi}=\cos(2z)+i\sin(2z)$, you find that the real part of the integral of $f(z)$ is the same as the original integral.

Comment: Is it because sin(2z) is an even function and integration with symmetry limits would equal zero?

Comment: @snowman sine is **odd**

Comment: if that's the case then what would you do if the original integral had sine instead of cosine?

Comment: but even if it wouldn't be zero all along... you can still use this argument to add some real/imaginary part and then strike it out by taking the imaginary/real part. This is due to the linearity of the integral (and orthogonality of real and imaginary part).

Comment: "if that's the case" ?? You do not know whether sine is odd?

Comment: no I know sine is odd, that was a mistake. I mean what if the original integral at the top was $\sin(2x)$ instead. How would you write the $f(z)$?

Comment: @snowman: If the original numerator were $\sin(2x)$, this particular integral would vanish because the integrand is odd and the integral converges absolutely. (In general, it _might_ be helpful to replace $\sin(2x)$ with $\exp(2iz)$ and to consider the _imaginary_ part of the integral.)